# I want to be able to store and retrieve my research articles. Any suggestions?

Tags: database, frontend

I am beginning to design an application that will allow me to upload and retrieve my research articles. I need the ability to attach information to each article such as APA citation, annotated bibliography and meta tags for search. Can this be accomplished with front-end development or only with a back-end database?

Comment: No matter what your use case is (desktop app, website, etc..) , if you want to persist data then you will need some form of data store.

Comment: If you only had a front-end, where would you upload your articles *to*?

Comment: @RyanVincent...I'm learning to code and I wanted to practice by developing my own application.

Comment: @dimo414...that's exactly what I was trying to figure out. I wondered if I could imply an existing cloud storage API i.e. dropbox.

Comment: @mituw16...that's what I thought after doing some initial research but I wanted to be sure...thank you